# Remove Lottie import on mobile

Tags: react-hooks, gatsby, lottie

I'm using Gatsby for a static website and I import Lottie Light in some components to display animation on desktop.

However, I don't want to load those animations on mobile. Even if I dont load the Json file, the lottie_light.min.js is still importing. It hurts my lighthouse score.

Is there a way to prevent this import on mobile devices ?

Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, createRef } from "react";
import lottie_lightMin from "lottie-web/build/player/lottie_light.min.js";
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

const ComponentWithAnimation = ({ }) => {
  let animationContainer = createRef();

  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(true)

  const { ref: divdRef, inView: divIsVisible } = useInView({
    threshold: .4,
    triggerOnce: true
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
      setIsMobile(false)
      if (divIsVisible === true) {
        const anim = lottie_lightMin.loadAnimation({
          container: animationContainer.current,
          renderer: "svg",
          loop: false,
          autoplay: false,
          animationData: require('../../../animation.json'),
          rendererSettings: {
            preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice",
            className: "lottie-svg-class",
            id: "lottie-svg-id"
          }
        });
        if (divIsVisible) {
          anim.play()
        }
        return () => anim.destroy(); // optional clean up for unmounting
      }
    }
  }, [divIsVisible, animationContainer]);
  return (
 
        <div ref={divdRef} className="md:basis-1/2">
          <h2>Here is my</h2>
          {
            !isMobile ?
              <div className="animation-container mx-auto h-full max-w-full md:w-96" ref={animationContainer} />
              : ''
          }
        </div>

  )
}

export default ComponentWithAnimation
```

Thanks a lot for your help